# Boot loader error during installation of OpenSUSE 11.3

Tags: installation, boot, opensuse

I want to install openSUSE on my new laptop.
I partition my hard drive (600gb) with 5 parts:

> c: 97gb    d: 150gb e: 150gb f: 100gb
>   g: 50gb and 38gb unallocated part

In the openSUSE installation, the yast makes a 2gb for swap 14gb = root , 21 gb = home,
but in *Installation Overview* under *Booting* has a red error:

```
 the Boot loader Installed On a Partition that does not Lie Entirely Blew 128 GB .The system maight Not Boot;
```

What`s the meaning of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that you don't have a separate boot partition. Instead the /boot is under /, the root partition. It also means that /boot is very far from the beginning of the disk.

Various systems may have problems when /boot is too high on a disk. Since your /boot is under /, it is on the end of the drive. Error simply warns you that /boot may be too high on a disk and that such position could cause problems.

In general, best way to do partitioning is to have a small boot partition at the beginning of the disk and mount it under /boot. This way the root partition may be anywhere.

The error is there because BIOSes have limits on position of boot partitions. There is a nice article [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/partitions/partition_types-2.html#ss2.11) which explains several limitations which were common on BIOSes. Today, computers shouldn't have such problems, but it is always better to err on the safe side.

Comment: tanke you from your useful answer

Comment: where i make the boot partition (side of wich partion?)

Comment: and what about size of the boot partion?

Comment: @Milad Sobhkhiz It's not going to be very easy. If you're having problems, then you'll need a boot partition at the beginning of the disk. Try to shrink your C partition form 97 GiB to for example 96 GiB and place the boot partition in the space you got after shrinking. Also note that boot partition should be a primary partition.

Comment: @Milad Sobhkhiz  I think that 1 GiB should be enough for boot partition.